# print 2 conditions in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in mysql witch I have to print in mysql:

List only the name and weight of all the parts except the Red parts whose weight is greater than 15.0.

I've been trying to do it but i couldn't.

```
CREATE TABLE parts (
  partNum CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  name CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  colour CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  weight DECIMAL(3,1) NOT NULL,
  city VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (partNum)
);
```

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/not.php

Answer (score 0):

> <s>List</s> SELECT <s>only the</s> name <s>and</s> , weight FROM <s>of all the</s> parts <s>except</s> WHERE NOT ( <s>the Red parts</s> COLOUR = 'Red' <s>whose</s> AND weight <s>is greater than</s> >= 15.0

```
SELECT name, weight 
FROM parts 
WHERE NOT ( COLOUR = 'Red' AND weight >= 15.0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `name`, `weight` 
FROM `parts` 
WHERE NOT ( `colour` = 'Red' AND `weight` > 15 );
```